# Does RESTEasy have any helper to create Application configuration?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

Using Jersey I can configure my application by extending the [ResourceConfig](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.6/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) class which in turn extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`.

```java
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        super(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
        packages(MyApplication.class.getPackage().getName());
    }
}
```

Is there any similar helper class in RESTEasy? I need especially to scan packages in order to find resource classes. I know that it's possible in web.xml but I'd like to do it inside the code.

Comment: If the RESTEasy documentation doesn't give you an answer, then you might want to check out the Google Reflections API to roll something yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The javax.ws.rs.core.Application has only two methods to configure the resources like

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public Set getClasses() {
       return Collections.EMPTY_SET;
    }
    public Set getSingletons() {
       return Collections.EMPTY_SET;
    }
}
```

`I need especially to scan packages in order to find resource classes.`

I have this done this with [scannotation](http://scannotation.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) to look for example if a class is annotated with `@Path`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @PeterMmm. I even noticed that RESTEasy has a dependency to scannotation. I'm going to look into their source code to see how they use it.